# Bash CTRL to move cursor between words/strings

Tags: bash

I am use to using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key to move faster when using the left and right arrow keys (goes to end of a word, instead of one char at a time).

Can I do that in bash somehow?

I could probably code it, but I was wondering if there is something easier / already done.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

With the default readline key bindings, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> goes back one word, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> goes forward one word.

The default Ubuntu setup additionally provides <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+arrows like you're used to. These are in `/etc/inputrc` and specified as follows:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Not sure why we need three of them...

Comment: Its interesting that the bindings you specified dont match the bindings I figured out and mentioned in my answer.  I wonder what that discrepancy is.  Also, I am curious how you can determine what a character sequence is when looking at /etc/inputrc.  (for example.  how do I know what 1;5C means above?)

Comment: @bryan_ruiz: Different keyboards (terminal emulators, etc.) output different sequences. To see the sequence press Ctrl-v then the key. For me in PuTTY, Ctrl-v Ctrl-RightArrow gives me `^[OC` which is the same as yours. In `xterm` I get `^[[1;5` which is the same as Thomas'.

Comment: May I know why you gave 3 pairs? I thought one would suffice?

Comment: it would be better to do so by editing ```~/.inputrc``` instead

Comment: I can't believe how long I lived without this.

Comment: Editing ~/.inputrc may stop the 'system' one (/etc/inputrc) being loaded. 

Also note, the 'set -o' settings -- "set -o emacs" should give you emacs style key bindings on the command line, as opposed to e.g. "set -o vi" (after doing this you'll need to press ESC before trying to use w or b).

Comment: We also have [a similar question for PuTTY in particular](http://superuser.com/a/103097/45163).

Comment: This config file makes alt+arrow keys work on OSX.. dunno what the escape sequence is for ctrl on mac..

Comment: @DavidGoodwin After a bit of searching, adding `$include /etc/inputrc` will also load the system inputrc file.

Answer (score 45):

As Thomas explained, you can add the bindings to `/etc/inputrc`.

Another alternative so it loads every time you log in, is putting them in `~/.bashrc`  like this:

```
#use ctl keys to move forward and back in words
bind '"\eOC":forward-word'
bind '"\eOD":backward-word'
```

I learned that you can use `cat > /dev/null`  to look at the characters that your keyboard is sending, e.g., CTRL + right arrow shows:

```
^[OC
```

where `^[` is the same as `\e`   so that's where the code comes from in the `bind` command.

You can also look up bindings like this:

```
bind -p | grep forward-word
```

All of this is pretty damn awesome and I'm glad I found out some more power of bash.

Comment: I *think* this will only affect bash, whereas the `inputrc` solution will also apply to other programs that use readline, e.g. the Python interpreter, most other shells. Note that you can also put the commands in `~/.inputrc` if you don't have root, or don't want them to apply to all users.

Comment: For whatever reason this only worked for me when I swapped the order of your lines above. Further note. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS behind putty from Windows 8.1.

Comment: +1 especially for `I learned that you can use cat > /dev/null to look at the characters that your keyboard is sending`. #TIL

Comment: You can also simply type `read` and hit enter to achieve the same effect as `cat > /dev/null`. I'm lazy so I like solutions with less typing. :)

Comment: ctrl+4 crashes my cat (it sends ^/)

Answer (score 9):

A .inputrc in your home directory will cause ctrl+left to stop working on Ubuntu (for example).

To get everything working, add the following to ~/.inputrc:

```
# Include system-wide inputrc, which is ignored by default when
# a user has their own .inputrc file.
$include /etc/inputrc
```

credit to [f.kowal](https://serverfault.com/questions/386871/getting-5d-when-hitting-ctrl-arrow-key-in-a-terminal-on-freebsd)

Comment: I was affected by this part. I have ~/.inputrc for `set enable-bracketed-paste off`, because of which my ctrl+left/right stopped working. Your solution helped me. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$include /etc/inputrc`

in  `~/.inputrc`

Worked for CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)