# How to remap escape sequences in ITerm2 (Mac OSX)?

Tags: unix, escaping, iterm

I am using ITerm2 on Mac OSX, and I am trying to get the "skip words" hotkey (alt left, alt right) to work. On ITerm2, this is done by mapping `⌥ ← to b`, and `⌥ → to f` (found here: https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-forwards-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x). However, it seems like VIM's skip words function responds not to the `b` and `f` escape sequences, but to `[1;5C` and `[1;5D` (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611698/800735).

So it seems like I need a different set of hotkeys to skip words on VIM, and another set on Iterm2. What I would like to do is remap the escape sequences `b` and `f` to `[1;5C` and `[1;5D` in ITerm2, for some consistency. I know that its been done on XTerm by adding this to .Xresources: 

`URxvt*keysym.Meta-f: \033[1;5C
URxvt*keysym.Meta-b: \033[1;5D`

Is there an equivalent in ITerm2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first page mentioned (*[Use ⌥ ← and ⌥→ to jump forwards / backwards words in iTerm 2, on OS X](https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-forwards-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x)*) is vague about the "command line".  Given that it is talking about OSX, the author is likely referring to `bash`, and making some keys send useful bindings for that shell.  `bash` has *predefined* key bindings which treat the escape character as a *meta* modifier.

The other page (*[How to get Cmd-left/right working with iTerm2 and Vim (without requiring .vimrc changes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595633/how-to-get-cmd-left-right-working-with-iterm2-and-vim-without-requiring-vimrc/9611698#9611698)*) is solving an analogous problem with `vim`.  But `vim` treats the escape character specially.  So the binding used there is an escape sequence (which is not necessarily universally available — but if it works for you, not a problem).

Since `iTerm2` does not really know which program you are using, one approach to this would be to use the escape sequences which `iTerm2` sends (and `vim` accepts) in your `bash` ".inputrc" file.

Here are a few links discussing that solution (it is not a new problem):

- [Bash CTRL to move cursor between words/strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings)
- [How do I make ctrl-arrow keys move forward/backward a word at a time in Cygwin bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/488157/how-do-i-make-ctrl-arrow-keys-move-forward-backward-a-word-at-a-time-in-cygwin-b)

The `5` in the escape sequence, by the way, is for the <kbd>control</kbd> modifier, documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys).

Comment: Thanks, so Bash controls the mapping between escape sequences and functions (i.e forward-word, backward-word) in the terminal? The default mapping in ITerm2 was `f -> forward-word`, `b -> backward-word`. Where did those come from (since `[1;5C` and `[1;5D` seem to be the default for bash). I apologize for my ignorance regarding how terminals work ;P

Comment: Bash's escape-f and escape-b probably predate the control sequences used in xterm which iTerm2 supports.