# How to get readline working with python in alpine

Tags: python, docker, readline, alpine-linux

When I `apk add python3` in a Docker container running the alpine distribution, key combinations like `Ctrl <left arrow>`, rather than moving the cursor by whole words, print things like this (here, I typed 'spam eggs', then held down control and hit the left arrow key):

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  9 2015, 14:41:32) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> spam ham;5D
```

Merely `apk add`ing `readline` or `pip3 install`ing it does not by itself solve the problem.

How can I get readline working with python in this environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the key to this is mostly a case of getting readline working, but you might also have to handle your TERM correctly too.

I tried a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && \
  apk add python3 python3-dev build-base ncurses-dev bash && \
  python3 -m ensurepip && \
  pip3 install readline

COPY ./inputrc /etc/inputrc
```

With the inputrc from https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-env/blob/master/etc/inputrc, copied below:

```
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif
```

Here's a few links that I gathered this info from:

- [Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell)
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html
- [Bash CTRL to move cursor between words/strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings)

NB - I know it seems daft to be installing bash, but the `pip3 install readline` fails without it.  Also not ideal to have to be installing gcc etc, though you could cleanup after this if you need to by `apk del`-ing a few things.

With all this in place, it worked on my mac but not immediately on putty, though I suspect that just the TERM setup, YMMV.

Comment: What do you mean by "you might also have to handle your TERM correctly", @boyvinall?

Comment: Wow, this was a long time ago.  But I think I was talking about the TERM environment variable.  See some info here: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$TERM_variable  .. but something like `export TERM=linux` or similar